# Flutter Container() vs SizedBox() for dummy empty

Tags: flutter, dart

I am curious about this. I have seen many example using `Container()` for dummy hidden widget, for example, when loading has completed, then we `setState(() { _isLoaded = true; });`.
So we can use the state like this, right?

```
return _isLoaded ? Container() : LoaderWidget();
```

Or maybe using `SizedBox()` is actually better because it don't take much parameters and often used for padding anyway?

```
return _isLoaded ? SizedBox() : LoaderWidget();
```

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter: SizedBox Vs Container, why use one instead of the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716322/flutter-sizedbox-vs-container-why-use-one-instead-of-the-other)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In case of use as a placeholder:

**Container** if the widget has no child, no height, no width, no constraints, and no alignment, but the parent provides bounded constraints, then Container expands to fit the constraints provided by the parent.

**SizedBox** if the widget has no child, no height, no width, then width and height are zero.

Therefore, `SizedBox()` serves more as a syntactic placeholder.

Also, note that [SizedBox()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.html) is a `const` constructor but [Container()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/Container.html) is not. The first one allows the compiler to create more efficient code.

Comment: I was asking myself why in some code people used const to instantiate some classes, now I will definitively search this topic :) Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

regarding that [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)() class(widget) has more properties and methods, instantiating it will be a little more costly, so you are right using [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) is more efficient.
better yet, when you want to have a dummy empty widget use [Nil](https://pub.dev/packages/nil) widget. SizedBox creates a RenderObject. The RenderObject lives in the render tree and some computations are performed on it, even if it paints nothing on the screen.

We can do better, we can have a widget which does not create a RenderObject, while being still valid. The Nil widget is the minimal implementation for this use case. It only creates an Element and does nothing while it's building. Because the optimal way to use it, is to call const Nil(), it also comes with a nil constant that you can use everywhere (which is a const Nil()).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) widget, which will use `SizedBox` for the replacement as default.

Answer (score 1):

How about the `Placeholder` widget? The name itself indicates your use with it and it also has a `const` constructor. Though by default, it draws a gray X, but when you give it transparent as its color, that is solved as well.

```dart
return _isLoaded ? const Placeholder(color: Colors.transparent) : LoaderWidget();
```