# How to omit second condition

Tags: flutter, dart

How to omit second condition in conditional statement?

```
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        message != null
            ? Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                child: Text(message),
              )
            : null, // how to omit second condition?
      ],
    );
```

Wheh the second condition is null I get

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ════════ 
>   The following assertion was thrown building ExportData(dirty, state:
>   _ExportDataState#e723d): Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 4

Comment: `children: [ if (message != null) Padding(...), ...]`

Comment: @pskink do you think it's syntactically valid Dart?

Comment: @bereal yes i do think

Comment: @pskink Wow thanks. Don't you think it should be the answer then? :)

Comment: @bereal see https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour and type `^F promoActive`

Comment: @pskink yeah, found. Awesome, sorry about the hasty comment.

Comment: @bereal hasty? what hasty? you were just curious... btw notice that you can use `for` loop too...

Comment: @pskink Yeah, I just thought my comment could sound a bit aggressive, you never know in the internets. I think, this should be the actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer `SizedBox` instead of `Container`.

```
return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    message != null
        ? Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
            child: Text(message),
          )
        : SizedBox(),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Just curious - what is the advantage of using sizedbox over container?

Comment: See this link bro https://stackoverflow.com/a/57703904/4608334 @Mahori

Comment: I tend to agree with this option, also we can use const with SizedBox.

Comment: @VinothVino thanks for the link. I will start using a sizedBox as well for placeholder!

Comment: Yeah, it's more efficient. Happy Coding... @Mahori

Comment: Nice, +1 for using SizedBox :)

Comment: Thanks. Happy Coding.. @MidhunMP

Answer (score 3):

Generally i would return a Container() in this case.

```
return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        message != null
            ? Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                child: Text(message),
              )
            : Container(), // how to omit second condition?
      ],
    );
```