# How to set width of CupertinoButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

Am I missing something obvious here?
Setting minSize on CupertinoButton button sets width *and* height (see image).

How do I set only the width?

Thanks in advance.

[image: CupertinoButton's minSize]

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap it in a SizedBox and set width and height.

Example

```
SizedBox(
   width: 500,
   height: 200
   child: CupertinoButton(
       onPressed: (){},
       child: Text("Click Me", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
       color: Colors.green
   )
)
```

**NOTE:** It is best practice to use SizedBox as it is more efficient since you only need to change the width and height.

Check this. 
[Flutter: SizedBox Vs Container, why use one instead of the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716322/flutter-sizedbox-vs-container-why-use-one-instead-of-the-other/59594450#59594450)

Answer (score 2):

To give your `CupertinoButton` a specific `width` and `height`.

You can do one of the following:

1) Wrap it in a `SizedBox` and give it a Width and Height

Check code below for example:

```
 SizedBox(
   // set your width property here
   width: 100,
   // set your width property here
   height: 100
   child: CupertinoButton(
     ......  
   ),
);
```

2) Wrap it in a `Container` and give it a Width and Height

Check code below for example:

```
Container(
   // set your width property here
   width: 100,
   // set your width property here
   height: 100
   child: CupertinoButton(
     ......  
   ),
);
```

NOTE: for better performance, it is advised to pick Widgets according to the properties to be used. If you need some properties of the `Container`, go for the `Container` widget.

If you don't need most of the properties the `Container` has, go for the `SizedBox` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a Container() and set the width and the height from there