# Flutter: Are there any difference between these different layouts: Align, Center, Container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In flutter, Is there any difference between these layouts? -

**Concept - 1:**

- Center layout
- Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center, child: ...)
- Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center, child: ...)

---

**Concept - 2:**

- Align(
  alignment: Any Alignment, child: ...)
- Container(
  alignment: Any Alignment, child: ...)

Comment: Well, I think it all comes down to use cases and rendering cost, For instant container rendering cost is heavier than alight since it has a lot of fields and parameters. You can read this similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716322/flutter-sizedbox-vs-container-why-use-one-instead-of-the-other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, they are all using `Align`.

**Align:**

`Align` widget allows you to control the alignment, but if you don't pass in anything to the `alignment` parameter, it defaults to being centered anyway.

**Center:**

`Center` widget is inherited from the `Align` widget, not allowing you to set the `alignment` property, so it defaults to being centered. The main purpose of this widget is to make your code shorter and more readable.

This is the entire source code of `Center` widget:

```
class Center extends Align {
  /// Creates a widget that centers its child.
  const Center({ Key? key, double? widthFactor, double? heightFactor, Widget? child })
    : super(key: key, widthFactor: widthFactor, heightFactor: heightFactor, child: child);
}
```

**Container:**

`Container` widget wraps the `child` with an `Align` widget when you set an `alignment` property. It also supports other things, for example, if you set a `width` or `height`, it wraps the `child` with a `SizedBox`; if you set a `color`, it wraps the `child` with a `ColoredBox`; if you set a `padding` property, it wraps the `child` with a `Padding` widget.