# What's the most and the least expensive Widgets to build in flutter

Tags: flutter

in my case I need to set a widget in a column under a condition simply see :

```
isSomeBool ? MyWidget() : thatLeastExpensiveWidget()
```

I can use just `SizedBox` or `Container` simply, but are they the least expensive widgets in flutter that we can use or is there any widget made for this purpose only

and I'm interested to know also what's the most expensive widget that flutter can build

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Container()` and `SizedBox()` even if they are empty, they are still a full Flutter widgets that needs to be rendered and painted, so actually it's not the minimal widget that you can use just to shut down the analyzer when you need it in some cases,

I found the [Nil](https://pub.dev/packages/nil) package which provides a widget that defines 'nothing' but a class that the Flutter framework considers a widget but without any render or paint executed.

its implementation is actually just a few lines of code, and can be used like this:

```
    return Builder(
  builder: (_) {
    if (condition) {
      return const MyWidget();
    } else {
      return nil;
    }
  },
);
```

in case someone is curious about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which is least expensive because it makes you dive deep into source code of Flutter, who could answer you is the one that make/contribute this Flutter framework. But `SizedBox` & `Container` are simplest widget so maybe it is simplest as far as I know. `StatelessWidget` also cheaper than `StatefulWidget`. By the way, if you want to build your own widget, use `class StatelessWidget` instead of method like `Widget _buidYourOwnWidget()` because method reload each time app screen is rebuilt. In this case, `class StatelessWidget` is cheaper than method `_buidYourOwnWidget()`.

About what is most expensive, there are 2 kinds of expensive: about time or about space. About time, obviously is `Future`, because it can delay any how long you want. About space, it is your custom widget - because a widget may contain many children widget. Example, `Scaffold` is entire a screen, so it is most expensive about space.

Comment: thank you, your answer is right but it's doesn't answer what I need, the StatelessWidget is least expensive than StatefulWidget, I've got deep in the source code and I found that they both extends from Widget class, so basically even the StatelessWidget is valid for immutable widget but it still paint in the screen, so even the Container and SizedBox even if they are called just by Constructor, flutter still need to paint them, I need something that doesn't paint, just set as Widget without nothing

Answer (score 2):

You can only render the part you need using just the if statement and avoid rendering the else part as shown below.

```
child: Column(children: [
    ListTile(
      ...
    ),
    if (bool)
      Container(
        ...
      ),
  ])
```

Comment: thank you for your question, It fits to the case but I want to use the ternary operators in my case nd I just want to know the least/most expensive widgets

Comment: Generally in the course I did, the instructor used SizedBox, but I'm unaware of the additional cost it would bring.

Answer (score 2):

You must avoid usage of `IntrinsicHeight` & `Opacity` because it have expensive operation. Using `Opacity` in animation will cause frame drop.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommned `SizedBox` instead `Container` to add whitespace to a layout.

A Container is a heavier Widget than a SizedBox, and as bonus, SizedBox has a const constructor. [reff](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/sized_box_for_whitespace.html)

It is effectively the same. If you only use Container for width/height there might be a very minor minor negligible performance overhead. but you most certainly will not be able to measure it. [reff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55716668/12838877)

This is another way i ussually use by using list.

```
Column(
 children:[
  // other widget here

  // three dots is to add item to the list
  ...isSomeBool  ? [ my widget ] : []
  // if false => this will add empty list to the children, so nothing rendered.
  // but idk about calculation behind the list. 
 ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

dart supports conditional inclusion of elements in a list, so you don't need a dummy Widget, just like this for example:

```
Column(children: [
  Container(),
  Container(),
  Container(),
  Container(),
  if (isSomeBool) MyWidget(),
  Container(),
  Container(),
  Container(),
  Container()
]);
```

Comment: thank you for your question, It fits to the case but I want to use the ternary operators in my case nd I just want to know the least/most expensive widgets