# Is it true that setting a constants file in Flutter with `SizedBox` width and height make the app more performant?

Tags: flutter, performance, constants, sized-box

I came across [this article](https://medium.com/@vikranthsalian/flutter-for-better-performance-replace-sizedbox-with-compile-time-constants-e29777942946) in which the author says that it's more performant defining a file with all `SizedBox` width and height constants that is going to be imported each time a `SizedBox` is needed.

Is it true? Or how can we confirm what he says is true?
Or, what happens if I use his approach, would it be counterproductive?

Answer (score 0):

From the article:

> In a separate file, we can define all the SizedBoxes we need **as
> compile time constants**, using multiples of 4 pixels:

so the thing is *not* that wer'e creating a separate file, but rather the point is that we're creating `const`ants

The reason why `SizedBox` is better, since it can be `const` which is immutable and created in compile time so it's faster.

For example, this code works:

```dart
Scaffold(
      body: const SizedBox(),
    );
```

But this code will fail:

```
Scaffold(
  body: const Container(),
);
```

---

Also, take a look at [the docs](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/sized_box_for_whitespace#details):

> A Container is a heavier Widget than a SizedBox, and as bonus,
> SizedBox has a const constructor.

###### See also

- [Flutter: SizedBox Vs Container, why use one instead of the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716322/flutter-sizedbox-vs-container-why-use-one-instead-of-the-other)

Answer (score 0):

`const` means that the following object can and will be instantiated before the program is run.
So I don't think it will be more performant, its same.
 but I guess its just  better approach, to write your `const SizedBox` in separate file compare to write at each time, less typing and clarification as mentioned in the article.